# combine independent features in scikit-learn

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn

i've a small question about the combination of different feature-sets.

my situation:

there are documents with a title, some tags and a text to classify into "spam" or "ham". to extract the features out of the document (title and text) i'm using the approach described in the  [scikit-learn bugtracker](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2034#issuecomment-25317009).

After this step I can use `clf.fit(X,Y)` where `X` is the result of the `fit_transform`-operation and `Y` indicates whether the document is ham(`0`) or spam(`1`).

my question:

What's the best way to add the tags also as feature to handle? I thought about using `FeatureHasher` with a dict containing the tags as features ( e.g. `{"tag1": 1, "tag35":1}`) for each document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at `FeatureUnion` as seen [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html). It allows you to create multiple transformers and combine all of their outputs into one matrix.

Comment: jepp, i'm creating a ````FeatureUnion``` over all of the Features. My "problem" is how to handle the tags in a "proper" way

Comment: Are the tags unique? If so, you may be able to use OneHotEncoder . I think FeatureHasher will work as well, if understand your problem correctly. If you can post a little more detail about the data structure and tags maybe I can help more.

Comment: the tags are not unique. after i've combined the three things with feature union, i got an error, because the tags have another dimensionality then other document attributes

Comment: You can probably still use OneHotEncoder, I would try that as part of FeatureUnion. I don't think you should be getting an error though - this should be a feature space expansion only